# how to create youtube thumbnail link like youtube

Tags: asp.net, video, youtube

I have uploaded videos on youtube channel.

Using 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207284/Displaying-Videos-from-YouTube-Channel-in-ASP-NET

i am able to show all videos from channel. But i dont want to play video on my site.

I want to show video links on my website and when clicked it should go to youtube to play.

I want link to be thumbnail link of video link youtube shows us with total time on right bottom of thumbnail.

Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer here to use `thumbnail` to the `video`

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Retrieving_and_searching_for_videos

```
 foreach (MediaThumbnail thumbnail in video.Thumbnails)
 {
   Console.WriteLine("\tThumbnail URL: " + thumbnail.Url);
   Console.WriteLine("\tThumbnail time index: " + thumbnail.Time);
 }
```

Comment: but i also want to show the video duration on right bottom as youtube sows for every thumnail link

Comment: @user1750877 What does this `thumbnail.Time` denotes?